# Is there a single term for the sports "surfing", "skateboarding", and "snowboarding"?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, hypernyms, sports

The three sports "surfing", "skateboarding", and "snowboarding" share a lot of similarities, historical roots, and sometimes appear together in topical magazines. Is there a single term to call these three sports?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

They are all examples of board sports.

Comment: I usually see it as two words, though: "board sports".

Comment: +1 -- Just as an anecdote, my friends and I sometimes refer to board sports as "slidin' sideways" :)

Comment: +1 as a snowboarder this is the term I've heard used many times.  Not sure if it's one word or two though.

Comment: @MT_Head - you are right. I've spaced it out.

Comment: @AdrianThompsonPhillips The usual progression is that such terms start off as two words, then become hyphenated, then become a single word.

Comment: Don't forget shuffleboarding.

Comment: @MT_Head Yes, two words - but a single term, as requested

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen - I voted him up; I wasn't disputing the term, just pointing out that "boardsports" is not the usual spelling.  He's fixed it now.

Comment: Indeed - Google Ngrams reported exactly 0 uses of the word "boardsports," and somewhat more of the phrase "board sports."

Answer (score 7):

"Boardriding" seems to be a [popular](http://www.bing.com/search?q=boardriding) and sensible unifying term for these sports.

Comment: Bing?!...... :O

Answer (score 3):

How about "boarding" ? Because everyone of these has a board.

You could even say that for every board sport you want, e.g. wakeboard or kitesurfing is also "boarding"

Comment: Not a single mention of windsurfing in the whole stack so far. It is the 2nd oldest of the popular board sports =/ Kiting is _wind assisted suicide_. Does that count as a sport ;)

Comment: If you use a board for it ;)

Comment: Kitesurfing, windsurfing, wakeboarding and surfing have their own sub-genre: waterboarding.

Comment: Waterboarding is also a instrument of torture

Comment: That was the gag :P Besides, I think they prefer the term _information lubricant_.

Answer (score -2):

They are a part of the extreme Sport genre...

Comment: That's a bit too broad already. Extreme sports also include motocross, free climbing, skydiving, BMX, caving, rafting, paintball, bungee jumping, extreme ironing... (**Edit:** Okay, that last one is arguably a board sport as well, but still, the point stands.)